# Array of objects in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, json, object

I am new to PHP and trying to produce the following json output :

```
{
  "contacts": [
    {
      "id": "1",
      "name": "John Bob",
      "email": "john@bob.com"
    },
    {
      "id": "2",
      "name": "Johnny Mac",
      "email": "johnny@mac.com"
    },
      .....
  ]
}
```

and I have the following PHP code:

```
$final = array();
foreach ($contacts as $contact)
{
  .....
  $final[] = array(
      'id'           => (string)$id,
      'name'         => $name,
      'email'        => $email
    );
}
header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8');
echo json_encode($final, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

however, this outputs:

```
[
  {
    "id": "1",
    "name": "John Bob",
    "email": "john@bob.com"
  },
  {
    "id": "2",
    "name": "Johnny Mac",
    "email": "johnny@mac.com"
  },
]
```

I read over [this tutorial](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/php-api/current/_dealing_with_json_arrays_and_objects_in_php.html) and changed `$final[]` to `$final['contacts']` but still couldn't produce the desired json file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either:

```
$final['contacts'][] = array(..);
```

or:

```
$contacts_output = array();
foreach ($contacts as $contact) {
    $contacts_output[] = array(..);
}
$final = array('contacts' => $contacts_output);
echo json_encode($final, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

Comment: thanks the first method resolved the issue. can you please explain why?

Comment: Because it's adding the additional level of one more key and array that you require...!?

Answer (score 0):

```
 foreach ($contacts as $contact)
 {
   .....
   $final['contacts'][] = array(
             array( //insert all your array in contacts
               'id'       => (string)$id,
               'name'     => $name,
               'email'    => $email
    );
 }
```

Comment: @semagi can you give me the print_r($contacts)?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$final = array();
$final['contacts'] = array();
foreach ($contacts as $contact)
{
  .........
  $final['contacts'][] = array( 
    'id'       => (string)$id,
    'name'     => $name,
    'email'    => $email 
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$final = array('contacts'=>[]);

foreach ($contacts as $contact)
{
    $final['contacts'] []=
            array( //insert all your array in contacts
                'id'       => (string)$id,
                'name'     => $name,
                'email'    => $email 
            );
}
```